# Definition of an "expression" in the C and C++ standards

Tags: c++, c, expression, language-lawyer, standards

I'm asking this question because I'm updating my C and C++ course materials and I've had past students ask about it...

From ISO/IEC 9899:2017 section 6.5 Expressions ¶1 (and similar in the C++ standard):

> "An *expression* is a sequence of operators and operands that specifies computation of a value, or that designates an object or a function, or that generates side effects, or that performs a combination thereof. …"

Because the standards writers obviously choose their words carefully, the use of the phrase "sequence of operators and operands" seems potentially misleading to me.  It seems to indicate that to be considered an expression there must be more than one operator and also more than one operand.  Thus, literals like 123 or variables like XYZ would not be considered expressions because there is no operator, and they certainly can't be considered operands if there is no operator.

However, if 123 and XYZ actually are expressions, wouldn't replacing the phrase "sequence of operators and operands" with "sequence of one or more characters" or something similar be more accurate?

Please tell me what I am misinterpreting about what the standard is stating.

Comment: While C and C++ have a somewhat similar syntax and sometimes similar wording in their specifications, they still are different languages and the differences there are in the specifications can lead to quite big semantic differences for programs. So please be careful when you discuss both languages as what might seem similar may not be similar at all.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude:  Both standards use exactly the same phrase I am questioning.  Can you comment on my topic?

Comment: Your statement that "It seems to indicate that to be considered an expression there must be more than one operator and also more than one operand" seems wrong to me -- a sequence of *foo*'s can turn out to have length 1 (in which case there's just one *foo*) or even length 0 (in which case there are no *foo*'s at all) -- but your comment that "they certainly can't be considered operands if there is no operator" is a good one, given how the standard defines "operand". This does seem to be a small mistake in the definition.

Comment: The use of plural form is only demanded by the English language, not by the formal definition of a "sequence".

Comment: take a look in 6.5.1 Primary expressions

Comment: I think it is fair to say that "sequence of operators and operands" means "a sequence of zero or more operators and one ore more operands" — at least, I don't think you can have an expression that consists solely of operators (because operators have to operate on something).

Comment: Note that _`expression`_ is defined in [§6.5.17 Comma operator](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.17).  It's used in various places, including [§6.8.3 Expression and null statements](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.8.3).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: The expression `123` has no operators and no operands.

Comment: I don't think "sequence of one or more characters" would be an improvement. For example, the character `2` within the constant `123` arguably specifies a value, but it's not an expression. Expressions are defined in terms of sequences of tokens. A correct definition would refer to the grammar.

Comment: @KeithThompson: OK — I'm not sure what you're going to call `123`, but it looks pretty much like an operand to me — albeit one that doesn't have any operators applied to it.  I don't wish to extend the discussion.  I don't think that's helpful.  If your "I don't think" comment is aimed at me, then you're 100% misquoting what I said and therefore putting words into my mouth that I'd not say in this context.  (I see I did get a typo 'ore' where I intended 'or' — oh well).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler My "I don't think" comment was in response to the question (I quoted wording from the question and I didn't tag you). Since we're in language lawyer mode, `123` by itself is not an operand. The terms *operator* and *operand* are defined in N1570 6.4.6p2; "An *operand* is an entity on which an operator acts." By that definition, you can't have an operand without an operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the definition of "expression" in the C standard is incomplete -- but not in a way that causes any actual problems (other than to picky people like me).

The word "expression" in the text you quoted is in italics, which means that that is the official definition of the term. It's clear from other parts of the standard that `123`, for example, is an expression: it's a *decimal-constant*, which is an *integer-constant*, which is a *constant*, which is a *primary-expression*`, which is a *postfix-expression*, which (skipping multiple steps) is an *expression*.

It is **not** "a sequence of operators and operands". There is no operator, which implies that `123` is not an operand (this can be demonstrated by referring to the definitions of *operator* and *operand* elsewhere in the standard).

In practice, I've never heard of anyone, either a compiler implementer or a C programmer, having any real difficulty because of this incomplete definition. Compiler implementers refer to the language grammar. C programmers probably get a pretty good idea of what an "expression" is before reading the standard.

I'd like to see the definition of *expression* updated in a new edition of the standard. A definition that refers to the grammar rather than attempting an English description would IMHO be an improvement.

But if it isn't updated, we'll all keep using expressions without any problems.

As for C++, [Nicol Bolas's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58575010/827263) correctly points out that the C++ standard doesn't have a formal definition of "expression" like the C standard does. It does have similar wording at the top of Clause 8: "An expression is a
sequence of operators and operands that specifies a computation." -- but the word "expression" is not in italics and that sentence is part of a "Note", and is therefore non-normative. In C++, the standard defines expressions syntactically.

Comment: The only way the Standards make any sense is if readers are expected to fill in the gaps.  Fixing the standard to eliminate gaps might be a good thing, but there are enough gaps it would require a major overhaul, and if the Standard isn't going to do that it would be better to have it explicitly acknowledge its incompleteness.

Comment: Compiler writers only use the std when something is not clear for them or the committee. When things seem clear, the std text is ignored (and best ignored given its abject quality level).

Comment: @curiousguy: What would a compiler writer refer to other than the standard?

Comment: @KeithThompson Strange question. What would they *not* refer to? Why would they focus only on the std?

Comment: @curiousguy Because the standard defines the language. For C, for example, if the standard says one thing and K&R says something else, I'd expect any compiler implementer to follow the standard. I disagree about the standard's quality. It's imperfect, but overall quite good.

Comment: @KeithThompson You have pointers to base class subobjects that don't actually point to base classes, pointers to objects that point to God knows what, lvalue which refer to object except sometimes there is not yet an object there... it's a mess at the fundamental level. The real world has pointer to base classes, etc.

Answer (score 4):

> and similar in the C++ standard

I don't know about the C standard, but [the C++ standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr#1) puts this statement in a *non-normative* notation. It has no normative value to C++, so it should be read as colloquial.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot of Primary expressions that have a separate definition in (6.5.1).
You just confused different entities; the definition you provided describes exactly what it should describe.

```
6.5.1  Primary expressions
Syntax:
   primary-expression:
     identifier
     constant
     string-literal
     (expression)
```

Comment: Yes, there's a syntactic definition of *primary-expression*. More relevantly, there's a syntactic definition of *expression* in C11 6.5.17. But the English-language definition in 6.5 paragraph 1 is also normative, and is not consistent with the grammar. This is, in my opinion, a flaw in the C standard (but not one that causes any practical problems).